# Deleted entries from R.string and now all strings are wrong?

Tags: android, string, resources

I've had this issue before but was able to revert to a previous backup - this time no such luck.

I deleted a key entries in the R.strings.xml and now all the strings in my program are incorrect as if the memory address has changed and its retrieving them in the wrong order -- is there as simple fix to this besides inserting an older copy of strings.xml??

Comment: try to clean-rebuild your project

Comment: @GideonKain goto windows >> show view >> click console  tell me any thing are there?

Comment: @GideonKain close all unrelated project

Comment: @GideonKain it is also raise because your xml file missing some thing

Comment: what key entries you deleted? and look at the problems windows in eclipse. and show that details..

Comment: no, but strangely the the strings that were bewing printed in place of the ones I had assigned to textviews and whatnot were actually the deleted entries - how in the world are strings that I deleted being displayed? I ended up just reverting - probably a hitch in the emulator or something

Comment: well it happened again, only this time I deleted some png images out of the drawable folder and now every image in my app is wrong - this is so frustrating as soon as I add a resource (bitmap, string, etc) I can never delete it or it will throw my app into chaos?

Answer (score 3):

Probably problem of generated R.java and id's stored there.

Try:

1) delete gen folder in Package explorer, Exlipse will shortly recreate this (rebuild resources and string id's)

2) Use Menu->Project->Cleanup to completely rebuild your project.

Comment: thanks for the tips - I bet deleting the gen folder would have worked - I ended up reverting and adding the new value to the bottom ~ something to tinker with once everything else is working superb ^^

Comment: well it happened again, only this time I deleted some png images out of the drawable folder and now every image in my app is wrong - this is so frustrating as soon as I add a resource (bitmap, string, etc) I can never delete it or it will throw my app into chaos?